# Событие при отключении сервера Django

Tags: django, события, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Запущен сервер джанго. Пользователь через фронтенд создаёт и запускает некоторые задачи, которые крутятся на сервере в отдельном процессе. Также задачи добавляются в бд, в частности имеют статус активна/не активна. 
Собственно вопрос: можно ли при отключении (ctrl+c) сервера или его падении вызвать событие, которое перешлёт на обработчик, где можно уже реализовать нужные задачи, в моём случае изменить статус задач на неактивные и убить все процессы. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил в таблице для задач поле pid, в котором хранится id соответствующего процесса. При запуске сервера из БД достаются задачи, активные до падения и проверяется существование такого процесса. Если такого процесса нет, а его нет, то стартуем задачу и присваиваем ей pid. При повторном вызове метода ready очевидно задача не будет запущена снова.

```
from settings import OS
import subprocess

class MyConfig(AppConfig):

def ready(self):
    Tasks = self.get_model('Tasks')
    tasks = Tasks.objects.filter(status=1) #вытягиваем активные задачи из БД

    if OS == 'Linux':
        proc_list = subprocess.Popen("lsof -t -i" , shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split('\n')
        PID = [int(p) for p in proc_list[:-1]]
        for t in tasks:
            if t.pid in PID:
                pass #задача уже запущена, не стоит её дублировать
            else:
                taskStart(t)
    elif OS == 'Windows':
        proc_list = subprocess.Popen('tasklist /fo CSV', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).communicate()[0].split('\n')
        PID = [int(p.split(',')[1][1:-1]) for p in proc_list[1:-1]]
        for t in tasks:
            if t.pid in PID:
                pass
            else:
                taskStart(t)
```

С удовольствием выслушаю дополения.

Answer (score 1):

К сожалению вопрос очень требователен к среде, в которой запускается ваше приложение

Есть вариант воспользоваться следующим решением - в вашем wsgi.py можно объявить системный сигнал, который будет перехватывать Ctrl-C (нужно дополнить файл):

```
import signal
import sys

def my_signal_handler(*args, **kwargs):
    print('shutting down')
    sys.exit(0)

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, my_signal_handler)
```

Также этот код можно оформить в виде обычного сигнала django:

```
my_django_shutdown_signal = django.dispatch.Signal()

def _forward_to_django_shutdown_signal(signal, frame):
    my_django_shutdown_signal.send('system')
    sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, _forward_to_django_shutdown_signal)
```

К сожалению такое сразу ставит кучу ограничений. Во-первых вам придётся запускать сервер с опцией `--noreload` т.к. django по умолчанию запускает сервер в многопоточном режиме и этот код будет оказываться вне основного потока, что приведёт к ошибке

```
ValueError: signal only works in main thread
```

Можно попробовать запускать через gunicorn, говорят помогает, но я не пробовал

Comment: Подумал сделать так, что при следующем старте сервера после его падения при старте проверять статус всех задач, и запускать их заного, если они до падения были активны. Почитав, нашел такой выход:
'from django.apps import AppConfig class MyConfig(AppConfig): def ready(self): print "ready"'
Но тут снова ограничение, так как ready исполняется дважды без опции --noreload и процессы будут дублироваться. Можно ли как-то обойти это? Единожды запустить некоторый метод при старте сервера.

Comment: @magrif на прошлой работе делали это через redis - создавали некоторое подобие семафора. Пока объект есть в redis - значит процесс выполняется. Можно туда pid активного запихивать и проверять потом жив процесс или нет. Можно ещё то же самое провернуть с pid файлами, но не хотелось заморачиваться